# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity error

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin to develop my android application. I get this error when I run the application. The main activity class extents from AppCompat. I understand that I'm required to use an AppCompat theme which I think I'm doing. 
In my Styles file I have this:

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
</style>
```

In my AndroidManifest application tag I have this:

```
<application android:label="SuperMarket" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="SuperMarket" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:name="md5aac27d1f54e5651bf56c7cf1fe703c82.MainActivity">
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error when my custom theme is a descendant of AppCompat theme.
I even tried to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead of my custom theme but still get this error.

**Edit**

here's the full stack trace

```
    08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282): 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282): Unhandled Exception:
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282): Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (Int32 layoutResID) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:5872 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at SuperMarket.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00009] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SuperMarket\SuperMarket\Activities\MainActivity.cs:29 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:cda09668-a60c-4d59-9b25-7606e0b35a8c (intptr,intptr,intptr)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at md5aac27d1f54e5651bf56c7cf1fe703c82.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at md5aac27d1f54e5651bf56c7cf1fe703c82.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono    (24282): 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (Int32 layoutResID) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:5872 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at SuperMarket.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00009] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SuperMarket\SuperMarket\Activities\MainActivity.cs:29 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:cda09668-a60c-4d59-9b25-7606e0b35a8c (intptr,intptr,intptr)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at md5aac27d1f54e5651bf56c7cf1fe703c82.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at md5aac27d1f54e5651bf56c7cf1fe703c82.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
08-02 04:06:41.567 E/mono-rt (24282):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace containing your error. It may be that the error is coming from something other than what you are thinking.

Comment: added the stack trace

Comment: I do not use Xamarin, which is why I added that tag to your question, to help focus help on that particular environment.

Comment: Okay I'll add that in my OP to make it more clear.

Comment: Post your Activity Declaration and Fragment (sems like you are using one), this error may be caused by wrong importation of the Fragment class, try to remove the importation of the Fragment class and import the another one (if you are using a Fragment)

Comment: apparently this error was caused due to the corrupt desiger file. I rebuilt the project and ran it and the error went away

Comment: Oh, must be, the "build" systems some times play some jokes on us, glad you resolved :)